# Why the waypoints are working when they are spheres but with cylinder not?

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

The waypoints example is from the unity docs tutorial site.
When i put two spheres the enemies will go between them and also not good when they get to one way point they are not turning back sharp 180 degrees but they are like moving backward without turning and then turning. What i want to do is when they get to a way point to turn sharp 180 degrees on the place then to start walking to the other way point. How can i do it ? Shoud i add a state in the animator for that ?

The second problem is when i put the cylinder as waypoint with one sphere the enemies will go to the sphere and will stay there then will make rounds around the sphere they will never get to the cylinder.

This is a screenshot of the scene after baking it.
I set the Terrain to be Navigation Static and Walkable.
I also set the Spheres and the Cylinder to be Naviagtion Static and Walkable.

Guard and Guard 1 are the enemies(ThirdPersonController)

[image: Baked]

This is a screenshot of the scene the two enemies of the left the two spheres and the big cylinder.

[image: Scene]

This is the patrol script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Ai : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform[] points;
    private int destPoint = 0;
    private NavMeshAgent agent;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent> ();
        agent.autoBraking = false;
        GotoNextPoint ();

    }

    void GotoNextPoint()
    {
        if (points.Length == 0)
            return;

        agent.destination = points [destPoint].position;
        destPoint = (destPoint + 1) % points.Length;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (agent.remainingDistance < 1.5f)
            GotoNextPoint ();

    }
}
```

This is a shot video clip i recorded show how they are patrolling.
And also the main player is getting angry all the time not sure why.

[Clip](https://youtu.be/x7vjyUNbJOw)

Comment: You did add the cylinder to `public Transform[] points` in the inspector?

Comment: For the turning speed you need to change the `angularSpeed` property of the agent. It specifies the `degrees/s` turning speed.

Comment: Gunnar i did add the cylinder to the points in the inspector. That's when the enemies didn't patrol but stuck and make round on the first way point. If i remove the cylinder and only use the two spheres in the inspector then they patrol but not quite good.

Comment: Gunnar i did add the cylinder to the points in the inspector. That's when the enemies didn't patrol but stuck and make round on the first way point. If i remove the cylinder and only use the two spheres in the inspector then they patrol but not quite good.

Comment: Well, obviously, providing the points you want to actually use to that public is what you need to do. (I guess, you would use `empty gameobjects` as waypoints anyways.) If they don't patrol in that setup, you should add some debugging to your above code to see what actually happens. Add `Debug.Log`s.